# memory allocation codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have a such code:

```
struct Point
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    Point(int xx, int yy) :x(xx), y(yy) {}
};

class figura
{
protected:
    int x,y; 
    int cvet; 
public:
    virtual void Pokaz()=0;
};


class star:public figura
{
private:
    int R;
    int r;
    Point *ar;
public:
    star(int x1, int y2, int radc, int radk)
    {
    x = x1, y=y2, R = radc, r = radk;
    ar = new Point[11];
    }
};
```

What is with this line? 
`ar = new Point[11];` Error message is no matching function for call to `Point::Point()`. I don't know why, but it works on visual studio.

Comment: You haven't defined the default constructor for `Point`.

Comment: Creating arrays like that requires a default constructor to initialise each array element - use a std::vector instead. There are other issues with this code - protected data is A Bad Thing, and you need a virtual constructor in your base class.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, OH, thank you!